# jQuery: What does $({}) do, and what is the jQuery apply method?

Tags: jquery

I know $() is the jQuery function...  but what does $({}) reference/do?  I'm looking at Ben Alman's code in https://gist.github.com/705311

```
(function(jQuery){
  var o = jQuery({});
  jQuery.each({ 
    "subscribe" : "bind", 
    "unsubscribe" : "unbind", 
    "publish" : "trigger" 
  }, function ( fn, api ) {
    jQuery[ fn ] = function() {
      o[ api ].apply( o, arguments );
    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to figure out how this code does what it does.  Can someone break it down?  Also, what is the jQuery.apply() method?  I don't see it in the jQuery docs - I can only find a 4 year old jQuery apply() plugin, which I doubt is in core now.

There's a newer, less complicated version at https://gist.github.com/661855, but I'm more curious what/how the 0.X version of this code even worked.

..edit..
I realize that $({}) is an empty object wrapped in jQuery.  The question is, why do it, and how does he then end up having created $.subscribe(), $.unsubscribe(), and $.publish() from this tiny snippet of code, especially the `o[ api ].apply( o, arguments );` bit?

Comment: Others have explained what the code is doing, but as far as `.apply()` - it is not a jQuery method, it's a standard JavaScript thing as [explained at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code creates an object to use for the observer pattern.  Here's an explanation line by line:

```
// opening a self-executing anonymous function closure
// assigning global variable jQuery (see last line)
// to local argument jQuery (usually this would be $)
(function(jQuery){

  // creating a jQuery selector object to access the available methods
  // typeof $.unbind == 'undefined'
  // typeof $({}).unbind == 'function'
  // And more importantly this new object will be the container
  // for our observer pattern (see below)
  var o = jQuery({});

  // iterating over an object with new method keys to old method values
  // creating syntactic sugar for an observer pattern (footnote 1)
  jQuery.each({ 
    "subscribe" : "bind", 
    "unsubscribe" : "unbind", 
    "publish" : "trigger" 

  // here fn will be the the new method name and api will be the old one
  }, function ( fn, api ) {

    // a property of the jQuery namespace is created with the new method name
    jQuery[ fn ] = function() {

      // which calls the old method applying given arguments (footnote 2)
      // to our new observer container object
      o[ api ].apply( o, arguments );

    };
  });
})(jQuery);
```

footnote 1: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/hh201955.aspx

footnote 2: see http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Comment: Looks great!  I know $() is a function, but it's so easy to forget/ignore that a jQuery object actually is a jQuery function, with all the native function methods like apply in there too.  :P

Answer (score 0):

Per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/:

```
jQuery( object )
```

> object A plain object to wrap in a jQuery object.

So this is just one way of returning an object that has the jQuery object methods and properties available to it - without using any other object or element as context.  (`{}` is just a new JavaScript object without any additional properties.)

`api` is one of the above strings, e.g. `subscribe`.  `o[ api ]` returns the `subscribe` function off of `o`.  This function (as does any function) has an `apply` function - which is detailed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply.

Answer (score 0):

The o=jQuery({}) initializes  an emply JQuery object.The  jQuery[ fn ]= function() {
          o[ api ].apply( o, arguments );  chains the subscribe,unsubscribe,publish custom events to bind,unbind and trigger.I think the code hooks these methods to bind,unbind and trigger.Just see the Object dump in firebug.

```
(function(jQuery){
  var o = jQuery({});
  jQuery.each({ 
    "subscribe" : "bind", 
    "unsubscribe" : "unbind", 
    "publish" : "trigger" 
  }, function ( fn, api ) {
    jQuery[ fn ] = function() {
      o[ api ].apply( o, arguments );

    };
  });
 //watch o in firebug
   console.log(o);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery({});
```

Here, a jQuery object is created with blank object inside.  When a jQuery object is passed to the $() function, a clone of the object is created. This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one.

Example below is very explanatory.

**Cloning jQuery Objects**

> ```
> // define a plain object
> var foo = {foo:'bar', hello:'world'};
>
> // wrap this with jQuery
> var $foo = $(foo);
>
> // test accessing property values
> var test1 = $foo.prop('foo'); // bar
>
> // test setting property values
> $foo.prop('foo', 'foobar');
> var test2 = $foo.prop('foo'); // foobar
> ```